# use of substr in extracting the value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following value as shown ...

```
<xsl:variable name="abcbegid">
<xsl:value-of select="$atr/@lattier" />
```

which brings the value as  treId1, but I want to extract only the last digit that is 1 ,
please advise how to extract that through substr function

what I have tried is that..

```
<xsl:variable name="abcbegid">
    <xsl:value-of select=" substring ($atr/@lattier,5)" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: there is also substring-after and substring-before. maybe those come in handy? Best regards, Peter

Comment: can you please convert my example into that as I want to extract the last digit, Thanks inadvance

Comment: @peter Please advise..!!

Comment: Can you give some examples of possible values? Will there always be a single digit at the end of them, for example? Or can there be two digits, like "treld12", in which case would you want "2" or "12"?

Comment: @peter there will be only two values that are  treId1 and  treId0 , and I want to extract the last one that is  is 0 or 1 , always

Comment: When you do `<xsl:value-of select="substring($atr/@lattier,5)" />` what do you currently get returned?

Answer (score 0):

```
substring("wewewe4",string-length("wewewe4"))
```

returns "4"

Answer (score 0):

I think [Kevin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533905/use-of-substr-in-extracting-the-value/19535548#19535548) is good. Use that one or do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($atr/@lattier,'d')"/>
```

That would output the character after the "d".